# Explode PHP Function

Tags: php, arrays, string

Is there is any way to explode this string?

```
$img_name = "123_black_bird_aaaa";
explode("_", $img_name);
```

Now such image name contains more than one underscore. How can I explode it at first underscore and not concerning remaining string how much underscores are there?

```
$img_name = "123_black_bird_aaaa";
$array = explode("_", $img_name);       
$first_underscore_part = $array[0];
$remaining_string      = $array[1];
```

For example a name `"123_black_bird_aaaa"`

Now I want `"123_"` at index `0` of the array and `"black_bird_aaaa"` at index `1` of the array.

Comment: http://php.net/explode, see the parameter list.

Answer (score 7):

This is just a comment, the parameter list from: http://php.net/explode

```
 array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Do not upvote this answer, instead downvote the question and / or vote to close and delete it. Thank you!

Comment: I like the fact that you said not to upvote your answer, yet people are still doing it anyway.

Comment: That's because, as has been proven so many times on this site, people cannot read...though I have realised explode won't work because it omits the first `_` which the OP is actually looking at keeping so technically `explode` is the wrong answer.

Comment: @Sammaye: I beg your pardon: `list($first, $last) = explode('_', $string, 2) + array(NULL, NULL) and $last !== NULL and $first .= '_';`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$img_name = explode("_", $img_name,2);
print_r($img_name);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without `explode`.

```
$pos = strpos($img_name, "_"); //finds the first underscore position
if ($pos === false)
{ //we have an underscore
 $firstPart = substr(0 , $pos , $img_name);
 //Get the characters before the position of the first underscode
}
```

If you want `explode` anyway , @hakre answer is AWSOME.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string at first delimiter by passing value of limit parameter as argument using explode function.

Below is code snippet for  splitting the string at first delimiter using explode function

```
    $delimiter='_';
    $img_name = "123_black_bird_aaaa";
    $result=explode($delimiter,$img_name,2);
```